# WordPress. Get equal number of posts of each content type

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Let's say I want to show 30 posts: 10 of type "A", 10 of type "B" and 10 of type "C". Sorted by post date.

How do I do that?

I mean I can do

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 30,
    'post_type' => array("A", "B", "C"),
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

But it will bring me just 30 latest posts - not 10 of each of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function and pass in the types, and amount of each that you want, then run a WP_Query over them all, and return your posts.

e.g.

```
function so_getEqualPosts($number_posts, $post_types){

    $postsToReturn = array();

         foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {

              $args = array(
                   'post_type' => $post_type,
                   'posts_per_page' => $number_posts,
                   'orderby' => 'date',
                   'order' => 'DESC'
              );

              $result = new WP_Query($args);

              array_push($postToReturn, $result->posts);
          }

        usort($postsToReturn, function($a, $b) {
            return strtotime($a['post_date']) - strtotime($b['post_date']);
        });

    return $postsToReturn;
}
```

** Updated above to match OP Requirements**
Alternative is to use a StdClass;

```
$postsToReturn = new StdClass();
```

Then in each iteration add to class with:

```
$postsToReturn->$post_type = $result->posts;
```

Then you can call it with:

```
$posts = so_getEqualPosts(30, ["A", "B", "C"]);
```

Posts should then be accessible by:

```
$posts->A
$posts->B
$posts->C
```

etc.

This is untested, and very much on the fly, but should give you a starting point :)

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to use a StdClass, make `$postsToReturn` an array and simply `array_push($postsToReturn, $result->posts)` on each iteration. That'll give you an array of all the posts together, rather than accessible by post type in your final object.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but is it possible to get all these posts in one array sorted by time posted?

Comment: @Paradoxetion Yes, it should be. If you use the alternative method (`array_push($postsToReturn, $result->posts)`) you'll get an array of all the posts together. The difficulty here is, with each iteration, whilst you can sort using WP_Query (`'orderby' => 'date', 'order'   => 'DESC'`), type A will be sorted and added, then type B sorted and added, and so on, but the overall array won't be sorted (although each type within will be sorted).

Comment: You'd need to then do a sort on the whole array, which you could prolly do with usort, something like....

`usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['post_date']) - strtotime($b['post_date']);
});`

*See updated answer.*

Comment: Ok, got it, but why I couldn't just do $a = get_posts($args1); $b = get_posts($args2); $c = get_posts($args3); and then just merge + sort array? Or your method better in terms of speed and optimization?

Comment: You could, but there's a couple of considerations here. Firstly, `get_posts` uses `WP_Query` under the hood, but doesn't have the same power of `WP_Query` (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query for more info). 

Also, the above method accepts an array of post types, so its scalable should you want more than the 3 posts types in this example. Suppose you add a 4th, you'd need to instantiate a 4th array with get_posts, and so on, and you'd need to do it in your code.

Comment: I guess there would be some memory implications with instantiating many arrays, and going direct to `WP_Query` rather than through another function would probably offer up some speed optimisation too. But i'm no expert :)